# Get IndexOf method- binary search

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

Help with the comparing of the `names1[middle].compareTo (value)` line. I am getting a compiler error of:

```
1 error found:
compareTo(java.lang.String) in java.lang.String cannot be applied to (int)
```

here is my code

```
public int indexOf(String word)
{

    public int getIndex(String [] names1, int value)   
    {     
        int bottom = 0; 
        int top = names1.length-1;
        int middle;
        boolean found = false;
        int location = -1;

        while (bottom <= top&& !found)     
        {      
            middle = (bottom + top) / 2;            
            if (names1[middle].equals (value))       
            {     
                found = true;
                location = middle;
            }      
            else if (names1[middle].compareTo (value))  
            {   
                bottom = middle +1;   
            }       
            else       
            {       
                top = middle -1;    
            }    
            return location;  
        }    

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `names1` is a `String[]`, `names1[middle]` is a `String`. The `value` parameter, on the other hand, is an `int`. The compiler error you're getting results from the fact that you can't use `String#compareTo` to compare a `String` against an `int`. To fix this, you will probably need to change the argument type.

Additionally, I don't believe that your `if` statement would be legal even if you make this change. `compareTo` returns an `int` that expresses how the values relate to one another rather than a `boolean` saying whether they're equal. You'll need to update this statement to take that into account.

Hope this helps!